# Can an Attribute be used to prevent a method from being called?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a custom attribute that I can apply to methods that will prevent the method from being called when `Transaction.Current` is null. I currently have a basic attribute class that throws an exception if that item is null. Here it is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class RequiresTransactionAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public RequiresTransactionAttribute()
    {
        if (Transaction.Current == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("requires transaction");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this does not cause method calls to fail in my tests.

I've read that these attributes are converted to meta data and so this constructor is never executed because it's optimized out unless I specifically use reflection to cause the attribute to be executed.

Is it possible to prevent a method from being called based on such a requirement as mine using attribute approach, or perhaps some other better method?

Comment: wrong question. You really mean 'how can I prevent a method from being called under certain circumstances in some declarative way'.

Comment: No, you'd have to have your own method invoker and call everything through that. The custom invoker would check if the method had your attribute, and if so, do the necessary check before finally conditionally invoking the method you wanted. I guess I should note that frameworks like MVC have this kind of thing built in already for controller methods.

Comment: or look at code injection things - used to be called Aspect injection, hot topic for a while. But really its overkill, just call `MyGate.TxCheck` at the start of the functions, same way people call `Contract.xxxx` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With *very few exceptions* (attributes with inbuilt behaviour by the runtime, where the JIT is looking for them - like `[MethodImpl(...)]` or code-access-security attributes), attributes are *completely inert* - they exist purely as metadata. They aren't even instantiated as objects unless you use reflection to ask it to do so.

So no: you can't influence runtime behaviour like this **unless** you are using a framework that **goes out of the way** to look for attributes, instantiate them, and treat them as runnable code via methods that the framework itself checks. ASP.NET MVC would be an example of a framework that does this.

The other option is an IL rewriter such as post-sharp, where attributes are a popular hook for injecting additional code during weave.